# In C++ Enter and Exit void function calls with key presses

Tags: c++, function, void

I built a function that draws pixels on the screen. I then wrote code in main() that calls the function when I press the enter key. However, as soon as I let off of the enter key the function stops.

How can I modify my code so that the function starts when the first enter key is pressed and stops when the second key is pressed?

Comment: can you post the code you have now.  Hard to help when we don't know what you've already done

Answer (score 0):

You need to detect the enter key's pressed state changing from 'not pressed' to 'pressed'. When you detect that event, you perform a logical NOT operation on a flag variable (let's call it shall_i_draw).

Your drawing code should then test the flag variable rather than the state of the key.